# View .HTML com VRaptor. É possível?

Tags: java, html, controller, vraptor, view

Sou estudante de Análise e desenvolvimento de sistemas e adoro programar, estudei o básico do básico de Java e estou fuçando *frameworks* só para ter uma noção. Como faço pra retornar uma página HTML em um *controller* com VRptor ao invés de JSP.

Estou fazendo alguns testes com REST e não queria usar JSP. Com Spring boot, consegui apenas retornando uma *String*: `return "index.html"`. Com VRaptor ainda não encontrei um modo. É possível? Como?

Answer (score 3):

Se você usar o `result.forwardTo("/minhapagina.html");` no controller funciona, mas faz mais sentido você utilizar a JSP que permite que você crie código Java dentro do HTML, ou seja, páginas dinâmicas.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, basta usar `result.redirectTo("/index.html");` ou o `result.forwardTo("/index.html");` no Controller mesmo, que ele redirecionará pra você, mas como o @haykou disse, seria mais conveniente utilizar o JSP, mas nada impede o uso de HTML, php, ou outras extensões, desde que trate dessa forma no Controller.